# Facebook app login error - Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains

Tags: facebook

We're getting the following error when a user tries to use one of our facebook apps. This is a long established app that was working normally until recently. I just became aware of the problem today. I confirmed the correct domain is in place in the Domains field in app settings. You can see the error here by clicking on one of the image map buttons https://www.facebook.com/LesherCenter/app/602128116556236/

Anyone have any ideas what the problem is?

```
"error": {
      "message": "Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191,
      "fbtrace_id": "CwaEPJ4+X8p"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution need to add "https://apps.facebook.com/" in Valid OAuth redirect URIs under https://developers.facebook.com/apps/your-app-id/fb-login/settings/. Issue came up as we were preparing for the forced strict mode coming next month. Even though it is not yet enabled its blocking that domain

Comment: Is there any way to get the URL it is trying to load?